# NullPointerException: Does not every exception contain a cause?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I've tried calling this on exceptions universally and by default throughout my application:

```
String causeClass = e.getCause().getClass().getName();
```

But I'm getting `NullPointerException`s.

Is there a safe way to look for a cause and get the class name of the cause exception?

Answer (score 8):

As JustinKSU pointed out, sometimes there is no cause. From [`Throwable#getCause()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29):

> Returns the cause of this throwable or null if the cause is
>   nonexistent or unknown. (The cause is the throwable that caused this
>   throwable to get thrown.)

When this happens, `getCause()` returns `null`, therefore throwing a `NullPointerException` when you invoke `getClass()`. Perhaps you can use this instead:

```
Throwable t = e.getClause();
String causeClass = t == null ? "Unknown" : t.getClass().getName();
```

However, for debugging purposes, I find [`e.printStackTrace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) to be much better. This way, you can see where exactly is the exception being thrown. Here is a typical output from `printStackTrace()`:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
         at MyClass.mash(MyClass.java:9)
         at MyClass.crunch(MyClass.java:6)
         at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:3)
```

Answer (score 4):

The stack trace is different than the cause.  If you create an exception

```
new Exception("Something bad happened")
```

There is no cause.

If however, you create an exception passing in another exception, then there will be a cause.  For example:

```
try {
    //do stuff
} catch (IOException ie) {
    throw new Exception("That's not good", ie);
}
```

Then `ie` will be the cause.

If you are trying to determine which class throw the exception you can do something like this:

```
public static String getThrowingClass(Throwable t){
    StackTraceElement[] trace = t.getStackTrace();
    if(trace != null && trace.length > 0){
        return trace[0].getClassName();
    } else {
        return "UnknownClass";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your outcome shows, some `Exception`s (and some `Throwable`s in general) do *not* have a cause. As stated in the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29):

> Returns the cause of this throwable or null if the cause is
>   nonexistent or unknown. (The cause is the throwable that caused this
>   throwable to get thrown.)

As JG points out, `printStackTrace()` is a good alternative.